# CSS/Html emails in laravel5 using Mailgun

Tags: css, email, laravel-5, mailgun

I am facing an issue on how to send styled html emails in Laravel5 using the mailgun service. The emails are sent but css is not there.

Comment: Are you using `Inline Style`?

Comment: no, I am sending a view to which CSS already applied is

Comment: Not aware about `mailgun service` but I am sure if you will use `inline styling` instead of using `classes`, it will work.

Comment: do you have a simple example showing how does it work ? I found this repo . https://github.com/tijsverkoyen/CssToInlineStyles Is it the one I should use ? if yes , how ? this service is bad documented !

Comment: you can try this one. https://github.com/premailer/premailer/ Convert classes into `inline format`

Comment: Hope! if  your problem is solved now..  you can close this question.

Comment: this is a ruby on rails gem :p